# duplicated lines in simple text with numbering at first and middle and last

Tags: lines

Picture to see the problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAhXJ.jpg

I want every line will be just duplicated ,
and only number change every single line numbering (1, 2 3 4 5) until 100 or more.

There is other number can content the line (2015) so i want leave it alone not change or maybe can have a lot of numbers at 1 line so i want keep them same.

I hope someone can suggest any idea to do this faster.

I don't want copy line more than 100 time 
and edited manually each line.

picture to see the problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAhXJ.jpg

Comment: Step 1: pick your favorite programming/scripting language Step 2: start coding Step 3: ... Step 4: profit!

Comment: thanks for comment .but no idea yet

Comment: We're not here to code thinks for you for free. You need to show some basic understanding and efforts in order for you to get adequate help. Start following a simple tutorial in any language you prefer and you'll be able to do this in a day.

Comment: i'm asking for idea . or name of tool can do this ... example what best way to watch videos .. you say yeah youtube.com ...... this is all if you don't know . is not problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply run this Python script and copy and paste that:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    print("'title", i, " anything else' , 'title ", i, "' , '", i, " title anything else' , 'title 2015 anything'", sep="")
```

Or if you don't have an interpreter, you can use this online interpreter:
https://repl.it/languages/Python3

Comment: your answer was very fast thank god there is good people in this world ...i will try it ... with ( Python script  ) ..^______^ .thank you alot for your time if this help will save alot of time for me ...

Comment: what i can say  i'm so happy i search whole day but you are really great :)
thank you sir thank you